# How do I interact with GMSMapViews bundled with my test app in UI Tests?

Tags: swift, xcode, gmsmapview, xcuitest

I want to interact with my testable app's `GMSMapview` to write some UI Tests. But since its a third party SDK bundled with my testable app. I am unsure and unaware where and how to start.

```
func testPanMapToAddFavourite() {
        // Use recording to get started writing UI tests.
        // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.

        app.launch()
        app.debugDescription
        app.maps.element.pinch(withScale: 0.5, velocity: -1)//Note: The map in my testable app is not an accessible element. Hence requesting for a suggestion to interact with the GMSMap views for writing some UI test cases in Xcode (XCUITest) 

}
```

Comment: I discovered the answer for the question posted above. Include below line of codes from where you initialize the mapView.

 

mapView.accessibilityElementsHidden = false

        mapView.accessibilityIdentifier = "GMSMapView"